# Using saved values in Arrays

Tags: arrays, pine-script

I am trying to use the values saved in the array called enterShortClose_arr and then check to see if the value is greater than the close when triggered again.  The enterShortClose_arr values are correct, but the value in enterShortLHClose_arr is 0. If the condition is met, I want to save the close price into the array called enterShortLHClose_arr.

I am not getting any errors so I am struggling on how to fix this so i get the correct values.  I have tried multiple different ways and have been unsuccessful.  Here is an alternative method I tried that did not work either.

```
if barstate.isconfirmed
    for a=0 to array.size(shortCond_arr)-1
        if array.get(shortCond_arr, a) and array.get(enterShortClose_arr, a) > array.get(price2_arr, a)
            closeShort := array.get(price2_arr, a)
            array.remove(enterShortClose_arr, a)
            array.insert(enterShortLHClose_arr, a, closeShort)
```

Any help on how I can fix this would be greatly appreciated.

```
var enterShortClose_arr = array.new_float(0)
var enterShortLHClose_arr = array.new_float(0)

// Populate var arrays
if array.size(enterShortClose_arr) == 0
    for i=0 to array.size(s_arr) -1 
        array.push(enterShortClose_arr, 0.0)
        array.push(enterShortLHClose_arr, 0.0)

if barstate.isconfirmed
    for a=0 to array.size(shortCond_arr)-1
        if array.get(shortCond_arr, a)
            closeShort = array.get(price2_arr, a)   
            enterShort := array.get(shortCond_arr, a)
            array.remove(enterShortClose_arr, a)
            array.insert(enterShortClose_arr, a, closeShort)

            if array.get(enterShortClose_arr, a) < array.get(price2_arr, a)
                closeShort := array.get(price2_arr, a)
                array.insert(enterShortLHClose_arr, a, closeShort)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `array.insert()` function is used to insert a *value* at a specific *index* in an array. The syntax is `array.insert(array, index, value)`.
However, if the array is empty or the index is out of bounds, the function will not work as expected.

In your code, It seems you're trying to insert a value at a specific index `a` in the `enterShortLHClose_arr`. If the array is empty or if the index `a` is greater than the size of the array, the `array.insert()` function will not work.

Here I use `array.push()` function instead of `array.insert()` to adds a value to the end of an array.

```
if barstate.isconfirmed
   for a=0 to array.size(shortCond_arr)-1
       if array.get(shortCond_arr, a) and array.get(enterShortClose_arr, a) > array.get(price2_arr, a)
           closeShort := array.get(price2_arr, a)
           array.remove(enterShortClose_arr, a)
           array.push(enterShortLHClose_arr, closeShort)
```

The `array.push()` function is used to add the `closeShort` value to the end of the `enterShortLHClose_arr`. This ensures that a value is always added to the array, regardless of the current size of the array.